# how to create Uninstall process in the Windows forms application in vs2010?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, uninstallation

I developed one windows forms application in vs2010. And i created the setup of that project. Now i want to give the uninstall wizard to the user to with the setup of my project. And i created one web service for remotely accessing database. I want to call the web service method during uninstall process from my uninstall wizard or when user uninstall through control panel .

How to do this?

thanks.

Comment: The normal Installer lets you plug in code into Install, UnInstall and Rollback

Comment: @Henk Holterman :can you suggest some document on this?

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial can help you.

[How to Add Custom Action to Visual Studio Setup Project](http://hackermini.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-add-custom-action-to-visual.html)

Comment: It's working but i want to execute my code before uninstall process. And in this situation it is executing code after uninstall complete.

Comment: use OnBeforeUninstall instead of Uninstall.